# need to add comments in an existing xml document

Tags: c#

I need to add comments in an existing xml document.a sample xml is shown below i need to write code in c#.  XML serialization was used to generate this xml
any help would be great...
thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person>
<Name>Job</Name>
<Address>10dcalp</Address>
<Age>12</Age>
</Person>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
        string input = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><Person><Name>Job</Name><Address>10dcalp</Address><Age>12</Age></Person>";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
        XElement age = doc.Root.Element("Age");
        XComment comm = new XComment("This is comment before Age");
        age.AddBeforeSelf(comm);
```

This code gets the document, finds the element named "Age" which is expected to be under the root element ("Person") and adds comment before it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XmlWriter` to write the comment in following way:

```
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteComment("Add comment here");
```

Now, you serialize `XmlWriter` instance through your serializer.